# Gridview - Update

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm debugging somebody elses code, and they have used a GridVew, linked to a collection of classes. Few problems with it though, when they add a row, they can leave that without clicking the ok or cancel buttons

In a GridView is there any way, to throw an update when the user leaves a row other than clicking on the ok button, or is there a way to stop the user accessing other rows whilst you have a row that is being edited ?

The framework being used is 2.0.50727

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this ASP.Net? Which .Net framework version?

Comment: Yes asp.net (just added the tag) framework 2.5

Comment: Sorry .. correction 2.0.50727